# Are demons different from fallen angels?

Tags: angels, demons, difference

Is it true that demons are the spirits of the giant breed that was brought forth when angels intermarried with the daughters of men while fallen angels remain to be angels in a fallen state? Is there any authoritative verse in the Bible that exposes the difference?

Comment: can you add any citations to the initial statement? are you looking for a particular denominations perspective or purely biblical basis?

Comment: @depperm, purely Biblical basis

Comment: One reasonable theory is that the "nephilim" giants were the same people that anthropologists call "neanderthals", who *are* known to have intermarried with Europeans. Neanderthals were *not* supernatural demons.

Comment: @RayButterworth, but that's mixing evolution with Christianity, can it work because I know there is a conflict based on the age where carbon dating says the earth is millions of years old while Christianity says its barely seven thousand years old

Comment: @SoFewAgainstSoMany says "*that's mixing evolution with Christianity*". — Huh? I never mentioned anything about evolution. Neanderthals interbred with European people and became extinct through assimilation (hence the fact that unlike Africans, modern Europeans have inherited several percent Neanderthal DNA). That has nothing to do with evolution vs. creation; it's just what it is, and there's no reason Creationists should deny it. The only conjecture here is that ancient memories of Neanderthals are the root of the stories about Nephilim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to try and answer this from a biblical perspective.

There is a theory going around about *nephilim* that hypothesizes that they are ETs. Obviously this is false. However, it is an extension of the rather more common theory that demons are the offspring of human and devil. This comes from Genesis 6:4: "The Nephilim were on the earth in those days, and also afterward, when the sons of God came in to the daughters of man and they bore children to them. These were the mighty men who were of old, the men of renown."

However, while a straightforward reading may lead to the thesis in the question, that is, that *nephilim* are demons, it is not so simple.

Let's see what the word '*nephilim*' means. In my annotated ESV, I have a footnote telling me "or *giants*". According to *[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nephilim)*, this is indeed the Hebrew meaning of the word '*nephilim*'. Uh-oh.

Let's look at Genesis 6:4 again, this time with the NIV so we can see this verse in easier-to-read language:

NIV: "The Nephilim were on the earth in those days—and also afterward—when the sons of God went to the daughters of humans and had children by them. They were the heroes of old, men of renown."

We know that giants existed because of David and Goliath. Therefore, *nephilim* are in fact giants - however, *nephilim* likely refers to the offspring, not the fathers.

Therefore, the offspring of *nephilim* are *not* demons - they are giants.

What, then, are demons?

Well we know they can inhabit humans (Matthew 8:28, 17:14-18) - so, then, they are not physical beings, thus, they **cannot** be *nephilim*.

They are what most denominations teach - fallen angels, those who took Satan's side. Satan himself can inhabit people as well (Revelation 13), as he is an angels as well. Therefore, the fallen angels can take the form as spirits - demons.

Let's look at some more verses that tell us how demons work.

Rev 16:14: "These miracle-working demons conferred with all the rulers of the world to gather them for battle against the Lord on that great coming Judgment Day of God Almighty."

No humans can work miracles without God, as Paul tells us in 1 Cor 12:4-6: "Now there are varieties of gifts, but the same Spirit; and there are varieties of service, but the same Lord; and there are varieties of activities, but it is the same God who empowers them all in everyone."

Matthew 12:26: " And if Satan casts out Satan, he is divided against himself. How then will his kingdom stand?"

If the demons are not in fact Satan's fallen angels, then this verse makes no sense. We can conclude that the demons cannot be separate from Satan nor can they be human. They must be one and the same with fallen-angels. Furthermore, there is no verse in the Bible which explicitly or implies that they are different.

Comment: Okay but  I said the spirits of the nephilim after they died, are they the ones people call demons because the nephilim were an abomination

Comment: No, the dead are said to be waiting in Hades before their judgement. As the nephilim were born, they cannot exist in the spiritual realm - Jesus' sacrifice is what makes this possible for humans. Sorry for the confusion. Revelation provides a myriad of info about the behavior of spirits, demons, angels, and fallen angels. If needed I'll find some verses to support my theory.

Comment: I would gladly accept the verses to validate your theory, how comes the giants didn't have the spirits?

Comment: Give me a few minutes, but I think because of the way He created humans and things, giants would have to follow the same rules as all the dead rather than the fallen angels. I'll edit my answer with some verses about demons and such.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, when Jesus cast out a demon then he mentioned Satan? Then that clears this, I will accept your answer